# Error in installing unity editor: Shader compiler initialization error: failed to get ipc connection while installation, not building

Tags: unity-game-engine, installation, failed-installation

I recently installed unity hub and unity editor after totally uninstalling it and re-installing because it was not working. the editor had suddenly stopped working i don't know the reason why.

the editor showed vcruntime144.dll missing mcvruntime.dll or something like that missing.

I installed those files from dll-files.com and added it too. but it showed this error now.

[this is the screenshot of the error. Please click on the link and access it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGFQD.png)

what should i do? Nobody has this error. It sudenly stopped working. i scanned my whole pc but there wasn't any viruses.

My pc is fully compatible with unity. I am using unity 2021.5f version but i even tried on 2020.3f and it still showed the same results.

Answer (score 1):

[Screenshot of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faWDP.png)I downloaded a newer version but i think it is the same problem.
The error you got is the same as mine.
This error is kinda false as there is no problems with connections ipc,tcp, or anything web related.
It was the UnityShadercompiler(USC) not opening cause neither "VC_Runtime140.dll : VC_Runtime140_1.dll : MSVCP140.dll " were not in the folder where the USC.exe is located
Directory -> C:"where you installed unity""UNITY version"\Editor\Data\Tools
In this folder you have to add the dlls i mentioned before.
-*I hope it helps :)*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).